# Powershell script to create folder, website and deploy using MSDeploy.exe

Tags: iis-7, powershell, powershell-2.0

I would like to deploy a web application on Windows 2008 R2. I know the separate PowerShell commands to do various tasks. But I would like to put this into a nice PowerShell script.

I just need the syntax, can you please help me to do the following actions:

1. Test if `C:\Inetpub\MyWebsite` folder exists, if not, create it.
2. Test in IIS7 if `MyWebsite` exists, if not create it (I know how to `Import-Module WebAdministration` and call `New-WebSite`)
3. Now the complicated part. I deploy a Web site from a package prepared by Visual Studio 2010. VS supplies a `.cmd` file where I just need to execute it from a DOS prompt. This means I have to leave the PS Console, open a DOS Console to run that cmd file. Is it possible to run a `.cmd` file from within a PowerShell console ?

Comment: any full source code sample ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your questions:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

# Check for physical path
$sitePath = "c:\inetpub\MyWebsite"
if (-not (Test-Path -path $sitePath))
{
    New-Item -Path $sitePath -type directory 
}

# Check for site
$siteName = "MyWebSite"
$site = Get-WebSite | where { $_.Name -eq $siteName }
if($site -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host "Creating site: $siteName"
    # Put your New-WebSite code here
}

# Execute your .cmd here
c:\PathToScript\MakeMySite.cmd
```

You can run `.cmd` scripts from within PowerShell just fine.

Comment: Hi,  This is awesome. I could build around this to complete my PS script.

Answer (score 2):

I have also changed a little bit. Using the same Test syntax to test if a website exists or not:

```
if (-not (Test-Path -path IIS:\Sites\$SiteName))
{
   New-WebSite -Name $SiteName ...etc...
}
```

Also for executing the *.cmd file, I lift some code from the web and saw that people use & to execute external command. Hope that you are OK:

```
& c:\PathToScript\MakeMySite.cmd arg1 arg2
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run the .cmd file as administrator, you can use the following code:

```
    Start-Process -FilePath C:\PathToScript\MakeMySite.cmd -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "/y"
```